# How to use newer versions of Maven for builds in Azure Pipelines for CI/CD

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I need Maven version 3.5.3 or above to build my project hosted on github. The default version for [maven](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=vsts) used in Azure pipelines CI/CD is 3.3.9.
I can see that there is a way to install a different version of java using [Java tool installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/java-tool-installer). I don't find such an option in their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks) for maven.

But for [maven](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=vsts) it is possible to specify the

```
mavenVersionOption: 'Default' # Options: default, path
mavenDirectory: # Required when mavenVersionOption == Path
```

But being a newbie I don't understand how to install maven and specify a path here.

Any help on how to use a different version for my maven build in Azure pipelines CI/CD would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since I am on an Ubuntu environment I was able to get this running by using a script to download maven and by setting the path for maven as follows:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'

steps:
- script: 'wget http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.5.4/binaries/apache-maven-3.5.4-bin.zip'

- task: ExtractFiles@1
  inputs:
      archiveFilePatterns: 'apache-maven-3.5.4-bin.zip'
      destinationFolder: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)/maven'

- task: Maven@3
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    mavenOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.8'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    goals: 'clean install -P ballerina'
    mavenVersionOption: 'Path'
    mavenDirectory: '$(build.sourcesdirectory)/maven/apache-maven-3.5.4'
    mavenSetM2Home: true
```

You can find the yaml file that works for all OSes [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/riyafa/transport-http/076cca9978202d8ceb630b7ff8b419e408659981/azure-pipelines.yml).

Thanks @starian chen-MSFT  for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to these steps:

1. Download maven installer package and add to source control (You can download it during build/release too)
2. Add Extract files task (Archive file patterns: `apache-maven-3.5.4-bin.zip`; Destination folder: `$(build.sourcesdirectory)\maven`)
3. Add PowerShell task:

code:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=M2_HOME;]$(build.sourcesdirectory)\maven\apache-maven-3.5.4"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MAVEN_HOME;]$(build.sourcesdirectory)\maven\apache-maven-3.5.4"
Write-Host "##vso[task.prependpath]$(build.sourcesdirectory)\maven\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin"
```

4. Add PowerShell task to check version: `mvn --version`

Comment: Sorry about the ignorance, but how do I add the installer package to the source control?

Comment: Or is there a way to download during release? Can you please point to a documentation?

Comment: @RiyafaAbdulHameed Just check in or commit/push the installer package to VSTS repository. Regarding download file during build/release: https://blog.jourdant.me/post/3-ways-to-download-files-with-powershell)